# Analogue read example not working

Tags: arduino

I tried to run the [ReadAnalogVoltage example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadAnalogVoltage) from arduino.cc and followed the schematic to use the potentiometer, but it always show the 1023 value at serial monitor. I already tried other ports too, and other potentiometer... What is the solution?

Comment: You are really better off posting to the Arduino forum (http://arduino.cc/forum/). The community is huge and very friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you used that code in the page you linked, you should be seeing a float value printed in the serial monitor. i.e a value from 0.0 to 5.0

Your potentiometer may be faulty. Test the resistance of the potentiometer with a multimeter by testing the resistance between the middle pin and one of the outer pins, when you turn the potentiometer the resistance should change. [This page has some great information on how potentiometers work.](http://fddrsn.net/pcomp/examples/potentiometers.html)

Comment: It was the ATMega2560, i replaced it at work, burned the firmware and now it work perfect.